# Why is a complex function's derivative with respect to the complex conjugate zero

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Here's what I'm thinking about: if a function has a nonzero derivative it's dependant on its input variable. Likewise the contrapositive: if it's independent of the variable it's derivative with respect to that variable will be zero.

If $f$ is a function dependant on $z$, which can be given by its conjugate. Therefore $f$ is a function of the conjugate of its input, and should have a nonzero derivative.

Where did this thought process go wrong? I've seen this derivative referenced in a proof of the Cauchy Riemann equations and elsewhere.

EDIT: let f be complex differentiable

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with  it.  What makes you think there is?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

essentially the reason is that because $x$ and $y$ are independent variables, it follows that $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are also independent variables as there is a clear bijective transformation between them. So any "complex" function regarded as real in two variables $x$ and $y$ becomes then a function in the new variables $z$ and $\bar{z}$ and then you can define properties expressed in terms of these new variables, and those turned to be extremely useful like analyticity of a function meaning there is no $\bar{z}$ "involved" in the function (so analogous to having a function of only $x$ but not of $y$), harmonicity meaning that $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are "separated" but not mixed together etc - introducing the usual differential operators makes this rigorous but I think the intuitive meaning is clear.

Comment: Thanks. Why does a clear bijective transformation make them independant?

Comment: Is it like two complex variables, but for x and y to be expressed in terms of them one happens to be the conjugate of the other?

Comment: given $x$ and $y$ independent, $z=x+iy$ is given by one linear relation, so to get back you need another variable and it is convenient (and simplest since usually given the sum of two entities, to recover them it is easiest if you also know their difference) to take that variable to be $x-iy$ and call it the conjugate, so now you can recover uniquely $x$ and $y$ from $z$ and $\bar{z}$. The point is that intrinsically the conjugate depends on the original $x$ and $y$ and not only on the new variable $z$, like say something like $z^2$.

Comment: and the above can be made rigorous using notions like linear independence or algebraic independence since say any polynomial in $z$ and $\bar{z}$ that vanishes identically must be null, exactly the way it is with polynomials in $x$ and $y$; the confusion seems to be that denoting the conjugate the way we do by $\bar{z}$, we make it seem as it depends only on $z$, when that is not case as it actually depends on the "components" of $z$, namely $x$ and $y$

Comment: oh, I get it now. I think I can fit it in with the proof I was looking at

Comment: In the Wolfram mathworld proof I found of the Cauchy Riemann equations, it looks like both z and z conjugate are functions of the same x and y. Is this wrong?